Why are table cells varied in height after generation?
I'm generating an HTML template with Go, and inside the template I generate table with dynamic data:
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Rate</td>
        <td>7-day avg</td>
    </tr>
    {{range .ExchangeRates}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{.From}}</td>
        <td>{{.To}}</td>
        <td>{{.Rate}}</td>
        <td>{{.SevenDayAverage}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{end}}
    </tbody>
</table>

But I'm receiving the table with wrinked cells like here.

How I can fix this? I need properly formatted table

What does the  {{range .ExchangeRates}} do/contain? Can you post a [<>] snippet with example data from view-source of the browser and include the relevant CSS?

It's not clear why this would happen. Please post rendered HTML and not your source code. Table cells don't vary in height unless there's something wrong.

Try to apply CSS Styling to the table to ensure that the cells are evenly spaced and sized. You can use CSS properties like border-collapse, padding, and text-align to control the appearance of the table.
if needed Adjust the CSS styles as needed to achieve the desired appearance for your table.
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th, td {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    th {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>7-day avg</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{range .ExchangeRates}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{.From}}</td>
            <td>{{.To}}</td>
            <td>{{.Rate}}</td>
            <td>{{.SevenDayAverage}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{end}}
    </tbody>
</table>


What problem does this solve? Table cells are the same height by default. A valid table would render virtually the same with or without your styles.
